# Integrable function discontinuous within the graph of a continuous function.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like some help with the following exercise.

Let $R$ be a rectangle and $C\subset R$ the graph of a continuous function $\phi$. Suppose that $f:R\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous in all $R$, with exception of $C$. Show that $f$ is integrable over $R$.

The exercise is recommending to use previous exercises that I already did. Here they're:

## 1:

Let $C$ be the graph of a continuous function $\phi:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $\varepsilon$ be any positive number. Show that $C$ can be placed in a finite union of boxes $B_i=[a_i,b_i]\times[c_i,d_i]$ such that $C$ doesn't contain boundary points of $\bigcup B_i$ and that $\sum_i area(B_i)\leq \varepsilon.$

## 2:

Let $R$ and $B$ be rectangles and $B\subset C$. Consider the regular partition of $R$ and let $b_n$ be the sum of the areas of all rectangles that intersect with $B$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = area(B)$.

I'm really lost with this one, I think I must follow the same process of proving integrability in a rectangle $R$ but I don't know how to deal with the discontinuity.

Comment: What do you mean "let $C$ be the graph of a continuous function"? Is $C$ the domain of a continuous function? If so, how does this match the title, since $C$ is not necessarily finite?

Comment: @ElliotG Edited. $C$ is the collection of ordered pairs $(x,\phi(x))$.

Comment: Is this all Riemann integrability?

Comment: @Ian yes, it is.

Comment: Lebesgue theorem states that $f$ difined over a rectangle is Riemann intaintegrable iff  the set that contains the points on wich if is not continious has zero Lebesgue measure. In the first problem you proved that the set \mathcal{C} has  zero Lebesgue-measure